# Radio Button is not updating in database through ajax in codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, radio-button

radio button is not working, when i choose 2nd option it will stay in 1st option.

**ajax code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#btn_update').on('click',function(){
        var id = $('#id').val();
        var fname = $('#fname').val();
        var lname = $('#lname').val();
        var mobile = $('#mobile').val();
        var dob = $('#dob').val();
        var gender = $('#gender').val();
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url  : "<?php echo base_url('home/update_profile')?>",
            dataType : "JSON",
            data : {id:<?php echo $row->id ?>, fname:fname, lname:lname, mobile:mobile, dob:dob, gender:gender},
            success: function(data){
                //alert(data);
            }
        },window.location.href = '<?php echo base_url('home/list_user')?>');
        return false;
    });
```

})

**my view:**

```
<div class="form-group">
                                            <h4>Gender</h4>
                                            <div class="radio">
                                                <label>
                                                  <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="male"<?php if($row->gender == 'male') echo "checked"; ?>><span style="font-weight: bolder; font-size: 15px;">Male</span>
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="radio">
                                                <label>
                                                <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="female"<?php if($row->gender == 'female') echo "checked"; ?>><span style="font-weight: bolder; font-size: 15px;">Female</span>
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                            <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error("gender");?></span>
                                        </div><br>
```

**my controller:**

```
$data=array(
              'id' => $this->input->post('id'),
              'fname' => $this->input->post('fname'),
              'lname' => $this->input->post('lname'),
              'mobile' => $this->input->post('mobile'),
              'dob' => $this->input->post('dob'),
              'gender' => $this->input->post('gender')
            );
            $this->user->update_data($data, $this->input->post("id"));
            echo json_encode($data);
```

**And my Model:**

```
public function update_data($data, $id)
    {
        $this->db->set($data);
        $this->db->where("id", $id);
        $result = $this->db->update("user");
        return $result;
    }
```

it is all code of radio button and it is not updating in database.
it is stay on their first option which is male not going on female

Comment: **id="gender"** should be unique

Comment: means i don't get you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change **ID** in each `input` tag to make them different:

```
<div class="form-group">
 <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender_m" value="male"<?php if($row->gender == 'male') echo "checked"; ?>><span style="font-weight: bolder; font-size: 15px;">Male</span>
</label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
<label>
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender_f" value="female"<?php if($row->gender == 'female') echo "checked"; ?>><span style="font-weight: bolder; font-size: 15px;">Female</span>
</label>
</div>
<span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error("gender");?></span>
</div><br>
```

You have two inputs with the same **ID**, it's bad. 
When you're asking DOM by `$('#gender').val()` it takes the only first value. You should get `checked` as I understood.

```
var gender = $('input#gender_m:checked').val() ? 'male' : 'female';
```

Comment: then i have to change in ajax too

Comment: yes, before `ajax` you should define which one was `checked`, and do that by different **id**. One minute and I'll provide you this case

Comment: @ParthKhatri, I've fixed the answer, replace your `var gender` with mine, and also you can take my HTML, it was fixed before